# What do I put in the content section of module exports in "tailwind.config.js"?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, vite

I can't get Tailwind to work and I think it's because my configuration file is wrong?

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./public/index.html", "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

---

I installed Tailwind and used init:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KniW.jpg

I filled in the "tailwind.config.js" like this:

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/components/DropdownVue/DropdownVue.vue"], <---INCLUDED  DROPDOWN FILE
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

I created an "index.css" and imported the Tailwind modules in it like this:

**src/index.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;  <-----INCLUDED IMPORTS
@tailwind utilities;

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Noto Serif", serif, Ariel, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #d7d7d7;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Serif&display=swap");
```

I started the build process and got an "output.css" file

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPGFB.png

that I included in my "index.html" file like this:

**public/index.html**

```
<link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

At this point it should have been working but it wasn't. I realized my config file was wrong so I changed it to:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./public/index.html", "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

but it's still not working. Do I have to run the build process again because I changed the config file?

What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "stripe-payment-vue3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.2",
    "@headlessui/vue": "^1.7.9",
    "@heroicons/vue": "^2.0.14",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.6",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

Comment: @morganney ????

Comment: It doesn't look like you installed postcss or autoprefixer. Did you follow the Tailwind/Vite installation instructions? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite

Comment: @EdLucas yes they are installed. I just edited the OP to include my package.json

Comment: Do you also have a `postcss.config.cjs` file that you can include?

Comment: I don't. Is that why it's not working?